# Generic Class Parameter in function

Tags: java, generics, dao

i have made a class like this

```
public class Item<IdType> {
    public IdType id;
    public String name;
}

public class Dealer<IdType> {
    public IdType id;
    public String name;
}
```

and a function in other class like this :

```
  public <T> boolean deleteById(Class<Class<T>> modelClass, T id) {
           daooperation();
           return true;
    }
```

what i want to do is when i call the function deleteById with parameter 1 is `Item<Long>` then parameter 2(id) should use `Long` datatype too 
other example is deleteById with parameter 1 is `Dealer<String>` then parameter 2(id) should use `String` datatype too. how to parse parameter 1(modelClass) to function deleteById or shoud i change the parameter 1(modelClass) in deleteById?
please someone help me, show me how can i do that.

Comment: You might want to look up **`Constraints on Type parameters`**.

Comment: sorry, can you explain more

Comment: Do you really need Class<ModelClass> for your DAO?

Comment: You are not using `modelClass` or `id` in your code anywhere, so they do not seem necessary in the first place. Can you come up with a situation that would require such a constraint?

Answer (score 1):

I think your methods should look more like this.

```
public static <I extends Item<T>, T> boolean deleteById(I item, T id) {
    doSomething();
    return true;
}

public static <D extends Dealer<T>, T> boolean deleteById(D dealer, T id) {
    doSomething();
    return true;
}
```

Comment: sorry but I don't want 'I' bound to just item class

Comment: Overload the function.  I updated the code section to give an example.  Generic "extends" does not support "or".

Comment: hi, thanks for the reply. i trying to make an API of DAO in android. so i didnt want to make a function to delete just one kind of model. my plan is to use reflextion to generate query for delete by the id.

Comment: why not just `public static <T> boolean deleteById(Item<T> item, T id)` and `public static <T> boolean deleteById(Dealer<T> dealer, T id)`

Comment: whats the term of the `<X extends Y>` part again?

Answer (score 0):

`Object.Class` method is your solution I guess

Answer (score 0):

Due to the way type erasure and Java generics work, the best you can do is:

```
public class Test {

    public static <T extends WithId<B>, B> boolean foo(T obj, B id) {
        obj.id = id;
        return true;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Bla<String> bar = new Bla<String>();
        foo(bar, "123"); // Works
        foo(bar,  123 ); // Fails
    }

}

abstract class WithId<T> {
    T id;
}

class Bla<T> extends WithId<T> {
    // ...
}
```

Comment: can i avoid creating new object to pass to foo?

Comment: The problem is that the only way to get type `T` from type `WithId<T>` is either by providing an object with that type or by passing the generic type explicitly. No, you can't have `Class<WithId<T>>`. Sad but true.

Comment: `public static <B> boolean foo(WithId<B> obj, B id)` would be simpler